# How can I build a base?

Tags: attracting-clients

I've been coding for a few years, and have a decent C.V. I've been on 2 internships, but never actually been payed for my work.

I'm going off to university, and figured freelance development would be a convenient solution for income, as opposed to working in the local supermarket.

I'd be comfortable doing full-stack work, but I'm sure most back-end work is in full-time jobs, as opposed to remote freelance jobs.

How do I build a client base. Should I use websites such as fiverr? Or is it really going out to random stores asking if they require a website?

Is freelancing the best option, or could I look for something like a weekend part-time job? I've heard there are little-to-none in software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you really need a client-base for this there are a lot of small to mid sized businesses who just need some maintenance of their business-application or automate some smaller tasks. Most students I know of where pretty busy with just one client. Seek a local company where you can easily stop by on afternoons. Most universities have some sort of board and there are even agencies specialized on that kind of work.